# Sphinx Search Api SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED not working

Tags: php, mysql, search, sphinx

I have the following PHP script and am using the sphinx search API. I want to search for a custom keyword but only in the title column of the MySQL database.

```
$s = new SphinxClient;
$s->setServer("localhost", 9312);
$s->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED);
$s->SetLimits(0, 10000);
$result = $s->Query("@(title) apple");
```

Unfortunately this returns nothing but when i use the following script:

```
$s = new SphinxClient;
$s->setServer("localhost", 9312);
$s->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED);
$s->SetLimits(0, 10000);
$result = $s->Query("apple");
```

I obtain the results, the problem is that the script searches in all columns.

What am I doing wrong?

I should also mention that on localhost (using XAMPP) it is working fine like in the first example.

Comment: did you check getLastError(), getLastWarning() ? They often tell you WHY a query fails.

Comment: No, i checked it after you told me and this is what it says: query error: no field 'title' found in schema

Comment: Yeah but i don't get it, i have title and content in my database and also in my source index the sql_query looks like this sql_query  =  SELECT ID, title, content, description, dateadded FROM feeds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I do notice, you dont explicitly note **which** index going to search - so the Query() searches ALL indexes.

Persumably then on one server you have an index that doesnt contain @title.

... for maximum compatiblity (so it doesnt matter waht other indexes add to the server, should probably search a specific index...

```
$s->Query("@(title) apple",'my_index');
```